# Cannot configure a GCP project when using DataProcPySparkOperator

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using a Cloud Composer environment to run workflows in a GCP project. One of my workflows creates a Dataproc cluster in different project using the [`DataprocClusterCreateOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator), and then attempts to submit a PySpark job to that cluster using the [`DataProcPySparkOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator) from the [`airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7520da441b99e17712b193bd2d4fbd7c73fb3166/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L1055) module.

To create the cluster, I can specify a `project_id` parameter to create it in another project, but it seems like [`DataProcPySparkOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator) ignores this parameter. For example, I expect to be able to pass a `project_id`, but I end up with a `404` error when the task runs:

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataProcPySparkOperator

t1 = DataProcPySparkOperator(
  project_id='my-gcp-project',
  main='...',
  arguments=[...],
)
```

How can I use [`DataProcPySparkOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator) to submit a job in another project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DataProcPySparkOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator) from the [`airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html) module doesn't accept a `project_id` kwarg in its constructor, so it will always default to submitting Dataproc jobs in the project the Cloud Composer environment is in. If an argument is passed, then it is ignored, which results in a 404 error when running the task, because the operator will try to poll for a job using an incorrect cluster path.

One workaround is to copy the operator and hook, and modify it to accept a project ID. However, an easier solution is to use the newer operators from the [`airflow.providers`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers) packages if you are using a version of Airflow that supports them, because many `airflow.contrib` operators are deprecated in newer Airflow releases.

Below is an example. Note that there is a newer [`DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator) in this module, but it is deprecated in favor of [`DataprocSubmitJobOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocSubmitJobOperator). So, you should use the latter, which accepts a project ID.

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocSubmitJobOperator

t1 = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
  project_id='my-gcp-project-id',
  location='us-central1',
  job={...},
)
```

If you are running an environment with Composer 1.10.5+, Airflow version 1.10.6+, and Python 3, the providers are preinstalled and can be used immediately.

Comment: If it is a simple Python script [on Google dataproc cluster] that we wish to run, how will the "job" argument be defined in  DataprocSubmitJobOperator? Is this even possible?